# How can I add/edit/delete group of contacts in iphone contacts from app?

Tags: iphone, contacts, addressbook

I want to add/edit and deleted the contacts in iphone contacts from my iphone app. And also allow the user to add group of contacts to iphone contacts from my app. It is possible to add multiple numbers from a same person in iphone? I know add and retrieve a single persion contacts from contacts in iphone? How can I do this? Please suggest me any tutorial/samples for this. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Apple's sample [Quick contacts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html). It explains all basic features about managing contacts in an iOS app.

Comment: Thanks for your response and guidelines. It is possible to add multiple contact numbers for a same person from iphone app? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible to have multiple phone numbers for each contact.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One more doubt, how can edit and delete the existing contacts from contacts app? Please give any idea. Thanks.